# With WebGL 3D graphics is coming to the browser, are there fundamental limitations or can it perspectively become as fast as "the real deal"?

Tags: web, opengl-es, webgl

I understand WebGL is currently just a subset of OpenGL and the performance isn't quite as good. Just out of interest, is it necessarily bound to be slower through the browser stack or can theoretically virtually all the power be passed through in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, WebGL has come to browsers several years ago, now the tech is somewhat mature: it's stable enough, there's community and ecosystem of libraries and services around it.

There're some limitations [to the API itself](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#6) as well as it's performance compared to native APIs (such as OpenGL, OpenGL ES and D3D). Mostly they're here to make WebGL more secure than its native counterparts. For example, for every draw call some validation are it order to make sure a programmer isn't doing something nasty (as accessing buffers out of bounds or trying to read uninitialised memory).

Due to the fact that all the checks WebGL implementations are doing now are absolutely necessary to provide a level of security sufficient for Web Platform, we're stuck with them, at least for WebGL and WebGL 2. However, maybe some "WebGL-Next" standard will find a clever way around that. And those checks a usually optimised by browser developers.

Comment: Thanks. I politely remind you that the "of course" part isn't as obvious to everybody as it is to you ;) Actually I didn't know any of this, and therefore also my question ;) So you are basically saying WebGL is slower than OpenGL because of security measures necessary on the web platform. Is this the only slow-down you are aware of and how confident are you that you're aware of all the major slow-downs? Thanks again! Just trying to get a better understanding of it.

Comment: Yes, there's another thing. WebGL's based on OpenGL ES, which is not fully compatible with desktop OpenGL. So on desktops WebGL calls are being translated into OpenGL and for Windows even into D3D calls (via [ANGLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANGLE_(software))). That introduces additional overhead.

Comment: There's pretty good description of how WebGL implementations work in [WebGL Insights book](https://webglinsights.github.io/index.html). There're also a bunch of good talks about WebGL performance, e.g. [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vW-QJDxYo3A).

Comment: Thank you for the insights!

Comment: Just a follow up question: Why is it only based on OpenGL ES in the first place? Why not a real OpenGL if the client supports it (desktop etc.) and an OpenGL ES fallback for mobile? Seems intentionally limited from the very outset the way it is.

Comment: @user777 AFAIK, the main reason is compatibility. Array of devices with GL ES 2.0-ish features is vast, where as modern OpenGL (not so modern is very similar to ES2, roughly speaking). So it was possible to implement WebGL on a vide variety of platform, including mobile. Now, when GL ES 3.0 comes closer to that reach, WebGL 2 (based on GL ES 3.0) is coming to Web Platform. Also desktop OpenGL has a fair amount of legacy staff in it, and if you remove all that staff, you'll end up with something very similar to GL ES 2.0 (GL ES was actually created with that motto in mind, IIRC).